# JQuery not registering Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a page that displays a list of products. The user can select the quantity of a product to order and then click the order button. This should place a reference to the quantity and the product ID in a Cookie. However currently the `button` is not even being registered. When I click on it nothing happens.

If I place the button outside of the `foreach` loop then it works. Does anyone know what is going on?

Below is the code for the list of products

```
    <?php if($products): ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
                    <h3 id="stock_code"><?= get_field('stock_code', $product->ID); ?></h3>
                    <p>Description: <?= get_field('description', $product->ID); ?></p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: <?= get_field('quantity_per_pallet', $product->ID); ?></p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                    Amount <select id="order_amount<?= $product->ID; ?>" name="amt">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn"/>
                    <?php endforeach;  ?>
            </ul>
  <? endif ?>
```

This is the code to be executed when the `button` is clicked

```
$("#orderBtn").click(function(event){
        //Show the order Box
        $(".order-alert").show();
        event.preventDefault();

        //Create the Array
        var productArray = [];   

        //If no Cookie exists, create one and add the Array
        if ($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined) {
            console.log("Create a new cookie");
            $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        //If the Cookie already exists do this  
        } else {
            console.log("Read the cookie");
            productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
            console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
            //Append items onto the Array
        }

        //Display the number of items in the Array in the Order Box
        $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
    });
```

I'd appreciate any help on the matter

Comment: You are duplicating orderBtn ID in the loop. Better assign it a class.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? would I not be duplicating a class then?

Comment: In DOM, IDs cant be duplicated. Either you put submit button out of loop and use ID selector as your using now or assign it a class if you want to have it displayed in the loop. Then you reference the form submitted using $(this).

Comment: Better show your fiddle. You might not want to have multiple forms.

Comment: @Javacadabra, class can be a common attribute. Id- is a unique Identifier. So it cannot be common to all. Try generating a new ID using a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ID on button. You have to use class if you want to assign event to multiply objects.

When you are using id selector jQuery assign event only to first object becouse ID sholud be unique.

Change:

```
$("#orderBtn").click(function(event){
..
}
```

To:

```
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
..
}
```

And HTML declaration:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn"/>
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
```