# JQuery multiple buttons in a list, specify which one was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am displaying a list of products. Each `li` contains a `h2` with the product stock code, `select` which allows the user to select a quantity to order and an order `button` which when clicked will add the stock code and quantity to a cookie.

Currently I've got it working so that when the button is clicked it prints the first stock code and the quantity chosen. However, I would like to tell `JQuery` which button was clicked so that I can get the value of the `li` elements it is associated with:

---

This is my `html`

```
    <?php if($products): ?>
                       <ul>
                       <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
                       <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code"><?= get_field('stock_code', $product->ID); ?></h3>
                        <p>Description: <?= get_field('description', $product->ID); ?></p>
                        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: <?= get_field('quantity_per_pallet', $product->ID); ?></p>
                        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                            Amount <select id="order_amount<?= $product->ID; ?>" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                       <?php endforeach;  ?>
                       </ul>
                   <? endif ?>
            <? endwhile; ?>
                <section class="order-alert">
                    <a href="#">Your Order</a>
                    <p>You have <span id="order_counter">0</span> items in your order</p>
                </section>
```

---

This is my `js` which currently only outputs the value of the first `li`

```
    $(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
            //Show the order Box
            $(".order-alert").show();
            event.preventDefault();

            //Create the Array
            var productArray = [];  

            //Get reference to the product clicked
            $stockCode = $(".stock_code").html();
            console.log($stockCode);

            //Get reference to the quantity selected
            $quantity = $(".order_amount").val();
            console.log($quantity);

            //If no Cookie exists, create one and add the Array
            if ($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined) {
                console.log("Create a new cookie");

                //Add items to Array

                //Add Array to Cookie
                $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
            //If the Cookie already exists do this  
            } else {
                console.log("Read the cookie");
                productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
                console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
                //Append items onto the Array

            }

            //Display the number of items in the Array in the Order Box
            $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
        });
```

---

Rendered HTML

```
 <ul>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CBL202659/A</h3>
                    <p>Description: Cavan Box                          <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 420</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount421" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CBL201764</h3>
                    <p>Description: Aldi Large Cavan Box               <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 420</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount419" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CBL20004/A </h3>
                    <p>Description: Cavan Box 6lb Tray Box Single     <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 840</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount417" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX SGLE CL </h3>
                    <p>Description: Single Outer Colour Cav Box        <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount415" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX SGLE BR </h3>
                    <p>Description: Single Outer Plain Cav Box         <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount413" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX HALF CL </h3>
                    <p>Description: Single Outer Half Crate Colour     <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount411" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX HALF BR </h3>
                    <p>Description: Single Outer Half Crate Plain      <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount409" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX DBLE CL </h3>
                    <p>Description: Double Outer Colour Cav Box        <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 500</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount407" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   <h3 id="stock_code" class="stock_code">CAV BOX DBLE BR </h3>
                    <p>Description: Double Outer Plain Cav Box         <br />
</p>
                    <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 499</p>
                    <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
                        Amount <select id="order_amount405" name="amt" class="order_amount">
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" id="orderBtn" class="orderBtn"/>
                                   </ul>
```

Comment: can you post the rendered html?

Comment: Why a new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116012/jquery-not-registering-button-click#comment37204229_24116012 ? You could have modified the earlier.

Comment: It's a little hard to read serverside code, but is that H3 (and the other elements) a direct child of an UL ?

Comment: @shaunakde it's a different question, the previous question was in relation to why my button was not being registered on click, this one is in relation to how I can get the values of the particular `li` the button is associated with.

Comment: @adeneo yes that is correct

Comment: Where is the `<li>` in your code? If you want so just add `$(this).closest('li')` in your button click code - this will give you the associated `<li>`

Comment: Then you have invalid markup, and the browser will change it to try and correct your mistakes, and your javascript selectors will never work.

Comment: Is it just me, or there are no `<li>` elements in the rendered html?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that the php code when rendered in html will not be a complete html. For instance, there is no `li` elements inside `ul` elements and the  `option` tags are to be wrapped in `select` tags. Please create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ with the rendered html and rephrase your question to get a proper solution.

Comment: So to prove our point you've posted the rendered HTML, and it's completely invalid, the only valid child element of an UL is a LI, not a H3 or anything else, those would be moved out of the UL as they don't belong there at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your problem I've created a fiddle to help you solve your problem.

Please look at the code below.

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CBL202659/A</h3>
        <p>Description: Cavan Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 420</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount421" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CBL201764</h3>
        <p>Description: Aldi Large Cavan Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 420</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount419" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CBL20004/A </h3>
        <p>Description: Cavan Box 6lb Tray Box Single</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 840</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount417" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX SGLE CL </h3>
        <p>Description: Single Outer Colour Cav Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount415" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX SGLE BR </h3>
        <p>Description: Single Outer Plain Cav Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount413" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX HALF CL </h3>
        <p>Description: Single Outer Half Crate Colour</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount411" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX HALF BR </h3>
        <p>Description: Single Outer Half Crate Plain</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 1000</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount409" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX DBLE CL </h3>
        <p>Description: Double Outer Colour Cav Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 500</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount407" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 class="stock_code">CAV BOX DBLE BR </h3>
        <p>Description: Double Outer Plain Cav Box</p>
        <p>Quantity Per Pallet: 499</p>
        <!-- Quantity Dropdown -->
        Amount 
        <select id="order_amount405" name="amt" class="order_amount">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to Order" class="orderBtn"/>
    </li>                               
</ul>


<section class="order-alert">
    <a href="#">Your Order</a>
    <p>You have <span id="order_counter">0</span> items in your order</p>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(".orderBtn").click(function(event){
     //Show the order Box
     $(".order-alert").show();
     event.preventDefault();

     //Create the Array
     var productArray = [];  

     //Get reference to the product clicked
     $stockCode = $(this).siblings('.stock_code').html();
     console.log($stockCode);

     //Get reference to the quantity selected
     $quantity = $(this).siblings('.order_amount').val();
     console.log($quantity);

     //If no Cookie exists, create one and add the Array
     if ($.cookie('order_cookie') === undefined) {
         console.log("Create a new cookie");

         //Add items to Array

         //Add Array to Cookie
         $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
         //If the Cookie already exists do this  
     } else {
         console.log("Read the cookie");
         productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
         console.log($.cookie('order_cookie'));
         //Append items onto the Array

     }

     //Display the number of items in the Array in the Order Box
     $('#order_counter').html(productArray.length);
 });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/LYpQg/)**

Please note that I've removed `id="stock_code"` because `id` should be unique in the page.